# Reverse even lines and put paragraphs in lists

Tags: python, list, file, line

I wanted to know how to operate on a text by inverting lines alternately. In particular I would like to reverse the even lines and leave the odd lines unchanged. I had thought of various solutions (for example I had tried to count the lines in a while, but I found some problems): I should count the even lines to be able to reverse them, but empty lines ruin this count. Another thing I would like to do is put each paragraph in a list, I'll give you an example:

If I had this text:

```
ἄνδρα μοι ἔννεπε, μοῦσα, πολύτροπον, ὃς μάλα πολλὰ
:νεσρεπἔ νορθείλοτπ νὸρεἱ ςηίορτ ὶεπἐ ,ηθχγάλπ
πολλῶν δ' ἀνθρώπων ἴδεν ἄστεα καὶ νόον ἔγνω,
,νόμυθ ὰτακ νὃ αεγλἄ νεθάπ ῳτνόπ νἐ 'γ ὅ 'δ ὰλλοπ
ἀρνύμενος ἥν τε ψυχὴν καὶ νόστον ἑταίρων.


:ρεπ ςόνεμέἱ ,οτασύρρἐ ςυοράτἑ ςὣ 'δὐο 'λλἀ
αὐτῶν γὰρ σφετέρῃσιν ἀτασθαλίῃσιν ὄλοντο,
οιοίλεἠ ςονοίρεπὑ ςῦοβ ὰτακ ἳο ,ιοιπήν
ἤσθιον: αὐτὰρ ὁ τοῖσιν ἀφείλετο νόστιμον ἦμαρ.
,εγ νεθόμἁ νῶτ
θεά θύγατερ,
.νῖμἡ ὶακ ὲπἰε ,ςόιδ

ἔνθ' ἄλλοι μὲν πάντες, ὅσοι φύγον αἰπὺν ὄλεθρον,
νασσαλάθ ὲδἠ ςετόγυεφεπ ετ νόμελόπ ,νασἔ ιοκἴο
τὸν δ' οἶον νόστου κεχρημένον ἠδὲ γυναικὸς,
νωάεθ αῖδ ὼψυλακ εκυρἔ 'ιντόπ ηφμύν
ἐν σπέσσι γλαφυροῖσι, λιλαιομένη πόσιν εἶναι.
```

I want to have this (with newlines replaced by spaces):

```
ἄνδρα μοι ἔννεπε, μοῦσα, πολύτροπον, ὃς μάλα πολλὰ
πλάγχθη, ἐπεὶ τροίης ἱερὸν πτολίεθρον ἔπερσεν:
πολλῶν δ' ἀνθρώπων ἴδεν ἄστεα καὶ νόον ἔγνω,
πολλὰ δ' ὅ γ' ἐν πόντῳ πάθεν ἄλγεα ὃν κατὰ θυμόν,
ἀρνύμενος ἥν τε ψυχὴν καὶ νόστον ἑταίρων.
ἀλλ' οὐδ' ὣς ἑτάρους ἐρρύσατο, ἱέμενός περ:
αὐτῶν γὰρ σφετέρῃσιν ἀτασθαλίῃσιν ὄλοντο,
νήπιοι, οἳ κατὰ βοῦς ὑπερίονος ἠελίοιο
ἤσθιον: αὐτὰρ ὁ τοῖσιν ἀφείλετο νόστιμον ἦμαρ.
τῶν ἁμόθεν γε,
θεά θύγατερ,
διός, εἰπὲ καὶ ἡμῖν.
ἔνθ' ἄλλοι μὲν πάντες, ὅσοι φύγον αἰπὺν ὄλεθρον,
οἴκοι ἔσαν, πόλεμόν τε πεφευγότες ἠδὲ θάλασσαν
τὸν δ' οἶον νόστου κεχρημένον ἠδὲ γυναικὸς,
νύμφη πότνι' ἔρυκε καλυψὼ δῖα θεάων
ἐν σπέσσι γλαφυροῖσι, λιλαιομένη πόσιν εἶναι.
```

And also some lists like this:

```
list1 =     ἄνδρα μοι ἔννεπε, μοῦσα, πολύτροπον, ὃς μάλα πολλὰ
    πλάγχθη, ἐπεὶ τροίης ἱερὸν πτολίεθρον ἔπερσεν:
    πολλῶν δ' ἀνθρώπων ἴδεν ἄστεα καὶ νόον ἔγνω,
    πολλὰ δ' ὅ γ' ἐν πόντῳ πάθεν ἄλγεα ὃν κατὰ θυμόν,
    ἀρνύμενος ἥν τε ψυχὴν καὶ νόστον ἑταίρων.

list2 =     ἀλλ' οὐδ' ὣς ἑτάρους ἐρρύσατο, ἱέμενός περ:
    αὐτῶν γὰρ σφετέρῃσιν ἀτασθαλίῃσιν ὄλοντο,
    νήπιοι, οἳ κατὰ βοῦς ὑπερίονος ἠελίοιο
    ἤσθιον: αὐτὰρ ὁ τοῖσιν ἀφείλετο νόστιμον ἦμαρ.
    τῶν ἁμόθεν γε,
    θεά θύγατερ,
    διός, εἰπὲ καὶ ἡμῖν.

list3 =     ἔνθ' ἄλλοι μὲν πάντες, ὅσοι φύγον αἰπὺν ὄλεθρον,
    οἴκοι ἔσαν, πόλεμόν τε πεφευγότες ἠδὲ θάλασσαν
    τὸν δ' οἶον νόστου κεχρημένον ἠδὲ γυναικὸς,
    νύμφη πότνι' ἔρυκε καλυψὼ δῖα θεάων
    ἐν σπέσσι γλαφυροῖσι, λιλαιομένη πόσιν εἶναι.
```

Now this is an example, but it can be also in English or another language, I just need to know how to do this operations.
I dont have much experience, so i thought someone on this forum could help me, thanks.

Comment: Where is the code [mre] you did? What you posted is not even valid python. [edit] and fix that please.

Comment: What do you consider as an even line? Is it a line with even length (including/excluding whitespaces)?

Comment: @MitchellOlislagers I mean like line 1 (odd), line 2 (even), line 3 (odd), line 4 (even). excluding white space

Comment: @PatrickArtner in the sense that the example is too long? do I have to reduce it? sorry but I have never used this forum much

Comment: Please read [ask] and what [mre] is. Essentially the code you post should be "runnable" by us after copy / pasting. Your code is not even valid python - you miss f.e. string delimiters. It is unclear where the text comes from ... a file? How do you read the file in? You also present 2 totally different overall "problems" where we care for one specific problem that you already tried to solve. What is yours? Reading a file line by line, somehow deciding if even/uneven and reversing one of the two before writing them back into another file? Splitting texts in paragraphs / lists?[..continued..]

Comment: Do you know how to open a file for reading? Do you have problems opening a file for writing?  Do you know how to iterate an opened file by its line? Do you have problems preprocessing the file to elimitate empty lines? Do you know how to do the iterating with a "linecounter"? Hint: `with open(filename) as f: for linenumber,line in enumerate(f): print(linenumber, line)`. Do you know what a modulo operation is how you can use it for even/odd detection? What would `if linenumber % 2==0: ...` do? [..continued..]

Comment: You show no code at all so we have no clue at all where you stand and what your problem is. We would need to write a solution specific for you - which is **not** what we do here - we help you fix specific problems, not do the full work for you. All the above problems have solutions on SO and are researchable via google: Google (and read answers) for
_**python how to print file with linenumber site:stackoverflow.com**_ and _**python even line from file site:stackoverflow.com**_ and _**python remove empty lines from file site:stackoverflow.com**_ then combine answers to solved your problem 99%

Comment: And **that** is exactly what SO is about - collecting answers to _specific_ questions that other people can use as lookup to combine it into a solution for their problem. Hence why we want _specific_ and _focused_ questions that are short and precise and help _others_ later on.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to get every other line reversed.

```
count = 0
lists = []
sublists=[]
newtext = ""
for line in text.splitlines():
    if len(line) == 0:
        if sublists:
            lists.append(sublists)
        sublists = []
        continue
    elif (count + 1) % 2 == 0:
        newtext += f'{"".join(reversed(line))}\n'
        count += 1
        sublists.append(line)

    else:
        newtext += f'{line}\n'
        count+=1
        sublists.append(line)
lists.append(sublists)
```

This will output `newtext`, containing the text with every other line reversed and `lists`, which is a nested list of each paragraph.